# When is "netsh.exe http update sslcert" available?

Tags: windows, netsh

On some PC's running `netsh.exe http update help` shows the command `netsh.exe http update sslcert` and it works, but on other PC's it does not. (Both running Windows 10.) When was it introduced / removed?

(`netsh.exe` is documented in various places, but it's unclear which documentation is up to date. [A](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Http/netsh-commands-for-http), [B](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netsh), ... None of them list  `netsh.exe http update sslcert`.)

Comment: Check the version of `%WinDir%\System32\netsh.exe`. I'm finding that version 6.x does not have the "update" option, and version 10.0.14393.0 does have it. I can't find any earlier versions of 10.x to compare. But this makes me think the "update" option is present in 1607 and newer.

Comment: @DougDeden The version here that does *not* have it is 10.0.14393 / 1607.

Comment: Oooh, that's very strange. I've found 10.0.14393.0 on several different machines so far, and they all have the Update option. Maybe it dynamically hides the Update option if it detects that there is nothing to update? (But then I'd think it would also hide the Delete option if there was nothing to delete, and it doesn't seem to do that.) I'm afraid that leaves you with having to do a Delete followed by an Add.

Comment: Actually I only know that `cmd.exe` printed `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.590]` and then `netsh http update sslcert` failed. I don't know the version of `netsh.exe` at that point. Since then it has somehow gained support for update, possibly from a Windows update.